# How can i convert ALL ascii to plain text

Tags: vb.net

This is the code:

```
Private Sub BtnConvert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConvert.Click
    ConvertedTXT.Clear()
    If TxtAscii.Checked = True Then
        While TheLength <> WaitingTXT.Text.Length
            ConvertedTXT.Text += (AscW(WaitingTXT.Text(TheLength)) & " ")
            TheLength += 1
        End While
        TheLength = 0
    ElseIf AsciiTxt.Checked = True Then
        ConvertedTXT.Text += (ChrW(WaitingTXT.Text(TheLength)) & " ")
    End If
End Sub
```

If you prefer, also have image: https://prnt.sc/idfi7v

Well, convert all text to ascii i get it, but the contrary no.

OBS: i declared the variable "TheLength" as double.

Comment: Why is TheLength a double? Why not an Integer?

Answer (score 0):

check this sample

```
Dim input As String = "Hello^world" ' change this into your input
Dim replaced As String = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "[^a-zA-Z0-9]", " ")
Console.WriteLine(replaced) ' output: Hello world
```